# JavaScript to .csv download fails: "Failed. No File"

Tags: javascript, html, download

Right now I'm just trying to get *anything* to work. My browser is Chrome `40.022`. When I click my download link, it initiates downloading but then fails with the error `Failed. No file`. What am I doing wrong? Is this a browser thing?

Javascript:

```
var fileName = "data.csv";
var csv = "abc, def, hij";
//I'm partially using angular in this page...
$scope.link3 = 'data:text/csv;base64,' + btoa( csv ); //forgive the variable name
```

HTML:

```
<a ng-href="aap.link3" download="data.csv">Hello</a>
```

Comment: Yes. Everything is contained in one page.

Comment: Oh, sorry I misunderstood. No, I didn't think I needed to do anything like that. I was under the impression it was all client-sided.

Comment: I think I'm completely lost then. I thought that name declaration was just telling the client via the html, "This is what the Javascript data you're downloading will be called." (where the data is just some array passed into a `blob`. Am I completely off the mark?

Answer (score 0):

I created a jsfiddle for your problem. There are 2 issues with your code:

1. In your case, `ng-href` data need to be interpolated
2. You must add `data` into whitelist for Href attrtibute, else it will
   be transformed into 'unsafe'.

https://jsfiddle.net/8o1v1uym/

Comment: when I run your code, the system kicks back csv, in the controller, is not defined?

Comment: What is the significance of the app.config statement?

Comment: I don't understand your first question, please clarify it.


The `app.config` part is to declare `data:xyz` protocol as "safe" to use. If you don't have that part of code, AngularJS directive like `ng-href` will attempt to modify the original url by adding `unsafe` into it. 
E.g `unsafe:data:text/csv...`